# Direct initialization of non-class types?

Tags: c++

I have read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) and my focus will be on the top section. I understand what the effects of direct initialization are on class types, but not on non-class types. It is explained that the effects on non-class types are:

> Otherwise, if T is a non-class type, standard conversions are used, if
>   necessary, to convert the value of other to the cv-unqualified version
>   of T.

As you can see in the above quotation, there is only mentioned something about conversions and what is being used to accomplish this, but what about cases where you simply initialize a non-class type using direct initialization, like:

```
int a(10);
```

How is this done? I cannot find the explanation for this in the article.

Also, the effect of this syntax for class types is explained, but what about those sweet non-class types?? It would make sense if it called some sort of constructor that returned a value as what is explained for class types. Hope I did not miss something obvious - that would be embarrassing :)

Comment: See the difference on [godbolt.org/g/T65tF9](https://godbolt.org/g/T65tF9). One may see the _difference_ clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are asking. But the full quote is actually this:

> Otherwise, standard conversions are used, if necessary, to convert the value of other to the cv-unqualified version of T, **and the object is initialized from the (possibly converted) value**.

So `int a(10);` does the same as `int a = 10;`.

Comment: Well, but to "initialize" is done differently (thus the categorization), so by saying that the object is initialized from the value is quite unclear to me. Like how is it initialized - is a constructor called? What value?

Comment: @T.C. can you help? Not sure if you get a notifications when I write a comment to an answer that is not yours, so tagging is worth giving a shot :)